# Can't set image path in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get an image path but can't get it. My code file is in the component folder in src and my image folder is also in the src folder

```
function ImageWithText() {
render(){
return(
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Lorem</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ispum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img scr={require('./../images/foodone.jpg')} alt=""/>
    </div>
    );
   }
  }
   export default ImageWithText;
```

Directory structure is

```
src-
   components-
       TextWithImage.js
   images-
       foodone.jpg
```

The error is

> ./src/Components/ImageWithText.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve './images/foodone.jpeg' in 'D:\react work\react javascript\react-tu\src\Components'

Comment: Post your component code, where you have used image.

Comment: You are using `./images ` which will look for the images in the Component folder. You should use ../images/foodone.jpeg

Comment: Try this - `<img scr={require('../images/foodone.jpeg')} alt=""/>`

Comment: that works! now there is no error but the image is not appearing on the front end

Comment: set with and height for the image tag..

`<img scr={require('../images/foodone.jpeg')} alt="" height={'100%'} width={500 } />`

Comment: @mohitchandel, check the image name and extension is correct.

Comment: Why you are adding `./` here `<img scr={require('./../images/foodone.jpg')} alt=""/>`, remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `<img>` attribute is correct, `scr` must be `src`. Take a look at this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp)

```
<img src={require('./images/foodone.jpg')} alt=""/>
```

Comment: Yes, you got that minor mistake! thanks the problem was "scr"

Answer (score 0):

Try ../images

Because you are saying that the js file is in components folder under src and image folder is also in src

So basically,

```
Src/
    Components/
        File.js
    Images/
        Cat.jpeg
```

With ./images you are looking for the image inside the same directory where the file.js is located, however, with ../images you go a level down i.e in Src/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you show your directory structure as well as the whole js file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<img scr={require('./../images/foodone.jpeg')} alt=""/>
```

Hope this will work

Comment: yes it is able to remove the error but the image is not showing on frontend

Comment: make sure the images has width and height. try to use inspect element to see whether image is loading on browser

Comment: i've checked every thing